# Xamarin android async task exception

Tags: android, xamarin, asynchronous, task, nullreferenceexception

I'm working on a Xamarin Android project, and my issue occurred randomly with an async task when i turn my device screen off/on, or when i go to another app, and return to my project app. The issue is not crashing my app since i handled the exceptions, but i don't know how to fix it.

The code of Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity
{  
 
 private ClassA classA;

 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    classA = new ClassA();
 }

protected override void OnResume()
{
   base.OnResume();

   Scan();
}

private async Task Scan()
{
    try
    {
        bool isServerAvailable = await classA.MethodA();

        // - result process                             
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("MainActivity", $"classA null: {classA == null} / exception:{ex.GetType().Name} / target:{ex.TargetSite} / helplink:{ex.HelpLink} / source:{ex.Source} / stacktrace:{ex.StackTrace}" );                
    }
}

}
```

And the code for ClassA:

```
public class ClassA
{

public async Task<bool> MethodA()
{
try
{
     // - HTTP web request / return true or false
}

catch (WebException ex)
{
    var exceptionCode = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    var errorMsg = exceptionCode.StatusCode.ToString();  
    Log.Error("ClassA", $"exception1:{errorMsg}");                  
    return false;
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Error("ClassA", $"exception2:{e.GetType().Name}";
    return false;
}
}
}
```

And the error printed by the logcat showed this:

```
2021-04-13 23:25:40.822 24368-12495/? E/asoq: Phenotype API error. Event # ckzo@6b0d1a99, EventCode: 5 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    asnv: 29501: Stale snapshot (change count changed - expected 189  but was 188)
        at asot.b(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):14)
        at asos.b(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):0)
        at asoq.a(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):4)
        at asoq.fT(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):12)
        at aciv.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):17)
        at btua.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):2)
        at ull.c(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):6)
        at ull.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at uri.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2021-04-13 23:25:40.823 24368-12495/? E/AsyncOperation: operation=CommitToConfigurationOperationCall, opStatusCode=29501 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Stale snapshot (change count changed - expected 189  but was 188), resolution=null}]
        at asoq.a(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):6)
        at asoq.fT(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):12)
        at aciv.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):17)
        at btua.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):2)
        at ull.c(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):6)
        at ull.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at uri.run(:com.google.android.gms@211212039@21.12.12 (120408-364497763):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

>E/MainActivity: classA null: False / exception:NullReferenceException / target:Void Throw() / helplink: / source:mscorlib / stacktrace:  at Namespace.ClassA.MethodA() [0x001b2] in <4c4350f04c95435983dd7984b1e1d5ec>:0 
      at Namespace.MainActivity.Scan() [0x000f3] in <4c4350f04c95435983dd7984b1e1d5ec>:0
```

I don't know why i got a NullReferenceException, because my object instance is not null.

Also, no log errors are printed from MethodA exceptions.

Any help on this?

Thank you.

Regards, Samih.

Comment: Have you check the part of `HTTP web request / return true or false`? Which line thrown this error?

Comment: Hi, the line that throws the error is `bool isServerAvailable = await classA.MethodA();`. My http web request doesn't work because i have a NullReferenceException for my classA instance. But when i check if it's null, it always returned false. So i don't know why i get an exception there.

Comment: I have checked your code again without ` // - HTTP web request / return true or false`. I use ` return true;` . There is no error. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the GC rolled in and collected the reference to classA, so it became null. Try moving the initialization of class A down to your `OnResume`. This way each time the app goes on that page it is still there. You can try to treat classA as a singleton a bit by also checking to see if the class is null or not and only reinitialize it if it is.

Ex:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
   base.OnResume();
   
   if(classA == null) {
     classA = new ClassA();
   }

   
   Scan();
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you, but this solution didn't worked for me. I updated the log with new informations.

Answer (score 0):

I've not the reputation to make a comment. So I have to write an answer. Looking at the stacktrace, seems that the NullReferenceException is throwed inside the MethodA(), could you please update the question with the full code of the method?